# How can I get an environment variable or a default string?

Tags: lua

In bash I can do `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/.config}` to get a default string if the given environment variable does not exist. How can I do that in lua?

I want to use it here:

```
plugBegin(os.getenv("XDG_CONFIG_HOME") .. "/nvim/plugged")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `or` you can do that if `nil` before `or`...

```
plugBegin(os.getenv("XDG_CONFIG_HOME") or "~/.config/nvim/plugged")
```

...that implements a default if that environment variable not exists (`nil`).
Since the environment variable holds only a part of the path and chaining (`..`) it before `or` with "/nvim/plugged" leads to a `nil` error if variable not exists i suggest to do...

```
local confd = os.getenv("XDG_CONFIG_HOME") or "~/.config"
plugBegin(confd .. "/nvim/plugged")
```

...that is much better and `nil`less.